# Clear Images from external JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, image, external

I am trying to clear images using external jquery file but it's not showing me even the alert.

Here are the images inside my div which I need to be cleared.

```
 $('#<%=thumbs.ClientId%>').append("<img class='LoadclickImage' align='left' style='height:48px;width:75px;' src='Uploads/" + document.getElementById("<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>").value + "/" + file.name + "' width='75' height='50' rel='group1' href='Uploads/" + document.getElementById("<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>").value + "/" + file.name + "' >");
```

This is my external JS file:

```
 self.ClearAll_button.click(function (e) {
     $('#<%=thumbs.ClientId%> img').hide;
     alert('You have cleared everything!');
     e.preventDefault(); 
     }
```

Comment: By external, do you mean a separate .js file?

Comment: Please show the actual HTML (what the browser sees), not your asp template.

Comment: Are you sure that your buttons are not NULL?

Comment: @Adreas-Yes it's calling from an external .js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%=thumbs.ClientId%>` makes very little sense in external javascript files. That's an ASP.NET server side tag that you could only use in ASPX/ASCX WebForms.

One possibility is to define global javascript variable in your ASPX page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var thumbsId = '<%=thumbs.ClientId%>';
</script>
```

and then in your separate js file use this variable:

```
self.ClearAll_button.click(function (e) {
    $('#' + thumbsId + ' img').hide();
    alert('You have cleared everything!');
    e.preventDefault(); 
}
```

Another possibility is to use a class selector instead of an id selector. And yet another possibility if you are running on ASP.NET 4.0 is to use [predictable ids](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40) thanks to the `ClientIDMode` setting.

Comment: @Darin-Thanks for your reply.It gives me an alert now but dosen't delete images.

Comment: @Darin-A small correction within your code worked out.For "hide" it should be hide();